# Is there a way to get a cross platform overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web

Currently I'm working on a website that is designed to run both on mobile devices and on regular computers. The problem that I'm facing is caused by the fact that I need to have a header and a footer with fixed positions.

The first thing that I tried, which seemed the most natural to me, was using position:fixed. It worked very well on my PC but it didn't work on my iphone (with ios4). So I googled it up a bit and found iScroll. [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) is a JavaScript standalone script meant to solve this exact problem. The problem is that this solution breaks the feature on a non-mobile platform. I also looked at YUI [ScrollView](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/scrollview/) but again it was broken on a non-mobile platform.

Currently I solved it by using iScroll only when I detect a mobile browser. But I'm looking for a cleaner and better solution.

Note: iScroll4 doesn't support ie, which I also want to support.

Comment: stick to browser detection for now

Comment: You probably want an entirely different stylesheet for mobile browsers, TBH.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no clean solution - you can try detecting "touch events" since those pretty much let you know when the user is going to need **iScroll**, and fire it up.

An easy way to detect touch events is the following,

```
    var $q = something...;
    try {
        document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
        $q.onmousedown = 'ontouchstart',
        $q.onmouseup = 'ontouchend',
        $q.onmousemove = 'ontouchmove';
        $q.touches = true; //used in other modules as well

        //position based on first-finger position
        $q.getPageX = function(e){
            return e.touches[0].pageX;
        };
        $q.getPageY = function(e){
            return e.touches[0].pageY;
        };

} catch (e) {
        //KEY BASED DEVICE
        $q.onmousedown = 'onmousedown',
        $q.onmouseup = 'onmouseup',
        $q.onmousemove = 'onmousemove';
        $q.touches = false;

        //grabbing the position based on Mouse position
        $q.getPageX = function(e){
            return e.clientX;
        };
        $q.getPageY = function(e){
            return e.clientY;
        };
 }
```

Comment: You think that this approach is better than detection based on the user agent field in the http request? and if so, why?

Comment: Because right now, the only browsers that support touch events, are way advanced to support css3 transforms used by iScroll. These browsers are, opera mobile, mobile safari, android default browser, fennec fox. If let's say a new browser is released tomorrow that supports these features, you will have to add one more case, while with such kind of detection it will just work. Also, companies choose to add support for features - when IE9 was released (that finally supports JS somewhat nicely)  lots of scripts and websites "broke" because they "forced" on IE9 the same hacks that they used on IE8.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, user agent detection is awesome, but it should be used carefully when new features are to be added to the newer versions of browsers - adding risk of breaking future compatibility.